# Is there a way to compile a ".pyx" into a ".pyc" with Cython instead of ".pyd"?

Tags: python, compilation, cython, cythonize

I was wondering : is there a way to compile a ".pyx" file (with Cython code) into a ".pyc" (thats works with windows and linux) : instead of : ".pyd" for Window or ".so" for Linux ?

I use the function cythonize.

Indeed, the ".pyc" works with both environnements : Linux and Windows.

I insist on this because I noticed my DLL ".pyd" and ".so" give minor and different results

Thank you

Comment: "Indeed, the ".pyc" works with both environments : Linux and Windows." This is **exactly why** it will not work: the **entire point** of using Cython is to create machine-specific code for performance reasons. "I insist on this because I noticed my DLL ".pyd" and ".so" give minor and different results" - then that is a separate problem that requires a proper [mre].

Answer (score 1):

No. `.pyc` files are Python bytecode files. They cannot contain the machine code Cython needs to produce to do its job.